# How do I get the color from Wordpress Gutenberg ColorPicker to save correctly?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

When creating a Gutenberg block type in wordpress I want the color value to be saved in an attribute and the ColorPicker to start at that color on refreshing of the page but the saved color value doesn't seem to be loaded to the ColorPicker on refresh/reload of page. How do I make the ColorPicker start with the saved color?

```js
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { createElement, Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor;
const { ColorPicker, PanelBody, PanelRow } = wp.components;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;

registerBlockType( 'test/colorpicker', {
    title: 'ColorPicker',
    category: 'layout',
    description: __( 'Testing the ColorPicker' ),
    icon: 'universal-access-alt',
    attributes: {
        color: {
            type: 'array',
        }
    },
    example: {},
    edit: ( { attributes, setAttributes, className } ) => {
        const { color } = attributes;
        return  ([
                <InspectorControls>
                    <Fragment>
                        <PanelBody
                            title={ __('Color Picker', 'test' ) }
                            initialOpen={ true }
                        >
                            <PanelRow>
                                <ColorPicker 
                                  color={ color }
                                  onChangeComplete={ (value) => setAttributes({color:value}) }
                                />
                            </PanelRow>
                        </PanelBody>
                    </Fragment>
                </InspectorControls>,
                <div
                    className={ className }
                    style={{
                        height: '400px'
                    }}
                >
                </div>
                ])
    },
    //Render in PHP
    save: (props) => { return null }
} );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value passed from the `ColorPicker` component is an Object and not an Array, so your edit function is not receiving it properly. It is confusing for me as well. Console logging the `value` from the `onChangeComplete` function of the ColorPicker will give you a hint.

You need to change the attributes specification, when registering your block, like so:

```
attributes: {
    color: {
        type: 'object' // <== Not 'array'
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved my day. I have color attribute as object now and only set it with the value.rgb part so it works perfectly with alpha too and saved space in the attributes-object.